# Sharing static linkage across translation units

Tags: c, nginx

I am implementing a C project, to be compiled inside/along with a bigger C project. I have a big `.c` file (no headers), that I made recent additions into. And the purpose of these additions are logically separable from the big C file. I want to split it to two `.c` files, for better maintenance. However I face a complication.

Although logically and preferably separable, these theoretical separated units(`.c` files), must share some of the static functions and declarations made inside the original file. When tried to create a header file to contain the common dependencies (which is the common procedure), I struggled because of the following reasons (and what I tried).

- The bigger project that my code is being buried into, has some of the same named definitions as my code, which is why they were static declarations originally. It works this way, but when I try to split the c files and create a header file, I had to remove the static keyword in some of them (to not get the error undefined reference), but this resulted in multiple declaration errors because of collision with the bigger project (expected but frustrating).
- I could not change the naming of such functions and structs because they are strict to work with the outer project.
- I am confused about what happens if the declaration in the header file is static, but the definition in the c file is not. Could not determine if this causes collision (theoretically it should?).
- I did not want to repeat the static common dependencies in the the separated files, it just involves making copies of code, and contradicts my purpose of making maintenance simpler.

I guess what it comes down to is, can I create such a header file or files, that the linkage (exported symbols) are only visible to the c files that imported that header, and not from the other translation units. And it is required that these units that I am created can see each others definitions (because of the header file only they included).

Even when I ask it, it seems improbable, however I may be approaching the problem from a wrong viewpoint, which I would also like to learn about. Is what I am trying to do is impossible, and I should keep it as a single file?

If useful, I am developing a module for the Nginx web server.

Comment: Please don't needlessly crosstag C and C++. If you want a C++ take on some problem, please ask a separate question.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: @Lundin Please don't disregard the question and down vote just because of this. This is a perfectly fine question two ask in both languages, even though I happen to be developing in C right now. I don't think asking the same thing only when I am developing a C++ project, which may contain the same answer, is in anyway beneficial to the community.

Comment: its fine to ask in either, but is it fine to ask for both? at the same time? I suppose not

Comment: There is no such thing as “static linkage.” There is a `static` keyword that gives internal linkage (along with other modifications to the declaration with respect to not using it). By definition, internal linkage does not cross translation units. The C standard does not provide features for controlling identifiers that are visible in some translation units (more than one) and not others. Some linkers have features for this, in which some object modules can be linked together and then stripped of selected symbols. You would need to identify the linker and other tools you are using.

Comment: Re “I am confused about what happens if the declaration in the header file is static, but the definition in the c file is not”: C 2018 6.2.2 7 says “If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.” The behavior would be up to the compiler and the linker.

Comment: @Rockybilly Not my down vote, but kindly read the C and C++ tag usage guidelines. You are essentially asking two questions at once. And yes the language matters a lot in this case since C++ has fundamentally different rules for initialization of static storage duration and other such variables.

Comment: Policy is not to mix C and C++ tags except for questions about differences or interactions between the two languages. Even if you want ask about both, people may search Stack Overflow in the future for answers specific to one of the languages, and mixing the tags dilutes the search results. You can ask about both languages in separate questions.

Comment: @Lundin No wouldn't make it a second time. Just was confident about my point. Still I thank you for trying to make it better. I accept it could be discussion point for meta, and not here.

Comment: @Rockybilly And I'm telling you that the difference between C and C++ is significant in this case. C has relatively straight-forward rules for static storage duration and internal linkage. C++ on the other hand is incredibly complex (as per C++11 and beyond), there's the "one definition rule" as well as multiple categories of storage: static, thread, dynamic etc etc. And the rules of initialization of these are not trivial either.

Comment: @Lundin You are correct, but my question only includes functions with the same signature, and structs with the same name. Which are subject to the same one definition rule of both languages (when not using extra c++ features outright, but the ones compatible with C). If I am incorrect, given the c++ tag is already removed, I would appreciate a short explanation, not as a part of the question, but as asking in comments.

Comment: @Rockybilly A struct in C is a struct. A struct in C++ is a class with public members. And as such, subject to different initialization rules than a C struct. RAII might be relevant to the question. C++ `namespace` might be relevant to the question. Again, as I told you from the start, it would be fine to ask the same question separately, but in the context of C++.

Comment: @Lundin Just as an academical argument, not to make it cocky or anything, the question is about declaration. C and C++ structs are of course different in nature. But not so much in declaration rules (at least in the scope of this question). Initialization and object instantiation are never mentioned, which rules out the concepts you mentioned that separates these languages (at least in the scope of this question). `namespace` is of course a solution to this problem in C++ terms, which doesn't however rule out the solution that would be suggested to C, is C++ applicable.

Comment: @Rockybilly best option is to make sure all functions are named differently, just by adding a character or two to the names of the appropriate ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the rare cases where it makes sense to include a .c file.

First, you have your two .c files, eg. module1.c and module2.c.  Then make a third file called mylibrary.c which contains just the following:

```
#include "module1.c"
#include "module2.c"
```

And compile *just* mylibrary.c.  While this means you loose the ability to reduce compile time by compiling modules separately, you still have the logical separation of functions in different .c files while only exporting the functions you want.

For static functions that need to be shared between the submodules, make separate headers for those functions to include in each submodule.

For example:

module1_priv.h:

```
static void mod1_internal1(void);
void mod1_external1(void);
```

module2_priv.h:

```
static void mod2_internal1(void);
void mod2_external1(void);
```

module1.c:

```
#include "module1_priv.h"
#include "module2_priv.h"

static void mod1_internal1(void)
{
    // do something
}

void mod1_internal2(void)
{
    // do something
}
```

module2.c:

```
#include "module1_priv.h"
#include "module2_priv.h"

static void mod2_internal1(void)
{
    // do something
}

void mod2_internal2(void)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention. I tried this, It is just, when logically separated, the declarations that belong to the first one, and used by the second one should be in such a place that, I have to include it in the middle of the code or something (If I am not to use a header file).

Comment: @Rockybilly You just need header files that have the declarations of the static functions put in the proper places.  Those headers would of course be private to your implementation.

Comment: I created a single header file, included it in both .c files. This solved the ordering problem. I could include the second .c file in the top of the first .c file. Although not pretty, I guess this is an edge case and has to be treated as such. Still curious about is there a standard suggested one however.